# STAN - Defining priors for dependent random variables

Tags: bayesian, calibration, stan, rstan

**Background**: I have a simulation model which has unobserved parameters. I created a metamodel using artificial neural networks (ANN) because the runtime was very long for the simulation model. I am trying to estimate the unobserved parameters using Bayesian calibration, where priors are based on current knowledge, and the likelihood of observing data is being estimated from the metamodel.

**Query**: I have two random variables X and Y for which I am trying to get the posterior distribution using STAN. The prior distribution of X is uniform, *U(0,2)*. The prior for Y is also uniform, but it will always exceed X i.e., *Y ~ U(X,2)*. Since Y is linked to X, how can I define the prior distribution for Y in STAN such that the constraint Y>X holds? I am new to STAN, so I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to proceed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Stan's [ordered vectors](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_28/reference-manual/ordered-vector.html) are what you need.  Create an ordered vector of length 2 (I'll call it `beta`) in the `parameters` block, like this:

```
parameters {
  ordered<lower=0,upper=2>[2] beta;
}
```

Ordered vectors are constrained such that each element is greater than the previous element.  So `beta[1]` will be your estimate of *X* and `beta[2]` will be your estimate of *Y*.

(To make sure I understand your model correctly: you have two parameters, *X* and *Y*, and your only prior knowledge about them is that they both lie in [0, 2] and *Y* > *X*.  *X* and *Y* describe some aspect of the distribution of your data - for example, maybe *X* is the mean of some *other* random variable *Z*, for which you have observations.  Do I have that right?)

I believe Stan's priors are uniform by default, but you can make sure of this by specifying a prior for `beta` in the `model` block:

```
model {
  beta ~ uniform(0, 2);
  ...
}
```